# C неправильное выполнение кода

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(a,d,s,x) {
    int g;
    g = a+d*s-x; 
    printf ("G=%d\n", g);
}
int main() {
    int *a;
    int *d;
    int *s;
    int *x;
    printf("[+] Enter a > ");
    scanf("%d\n", &a);
    printf("A = %d\n",a);
    printf("[+] Enter d > ");
    scanf("%d\n", &d);
    printf("D = %d\n",d);
    printf("[+] Enter s > ");
    scanf("%d\n", &s);
    printf("S = %d\n",s);
    printf("[+] Enter x > ");
    scanf("%d\n", &x);
    printf("X = %d\n",x);
    func(a,d,s,x);
}
```

При выполнении данного кода в консоли выходит это

```
[+] Enter a > 1
1
A = 1
[+] Enter d > 2
D = 1
[+] Enter s > 3
S = 2
[+] Enter x > 4
X = 3
G=0
```

а хотелось бы чтобы работал вот так

```
[+] Enter a > 1
A = 1
[+] Enter d > 2
D = 2
[+] Enter s > 3
S = 3
[+] Enter x > 4
X = 4
G = 5
```

Испольльзую Linux mint 19.1

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, заголовок вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Уберите `\n` из `scanf`.
2. Не нужно делать переменные a,d,s,x указателями
3. В функции func опущены типы аргументов

Как-то так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int a, int d, int s, int x) {
    int g;
    g = a+d*s-x; 
    printf ("G=%d\n", g);
}
int main() {
    int a, d, s, x;
    printf("[+] Enter a > ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("A = %d\n",a);
    printf("[+] Enter d > ");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("D = %d\n",d);
    printf("[+] Enter s > ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("S = %d\n",s);
    printf("[+] Enter x > ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("X = %d\n",x);
    func(a,d,s,x);
}
```